# Appointment Scheduler in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

I am looking for a gem or plugin for my rails application.  I want the user to be able to make an appointment for a certain day.  However, the calendar that will show up should have some days excluded.  Excluded days mean that there are no appointments on that day.

I came across calendar helper but I don't think it allows for exclusion of certain days.

Has someone come across a plugin like this?  It would be better if user was allowed to make appointments not just by day but also by hours in the days. For example 9:30 on 3/14/2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for something similar lately and here is what I found [event-calendar-rails-plugin](http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/07/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin/). Not tested though, because I was looking for something that could handle more complex situations, and ended up rolling my own solution.

Comment: any write up on the approach/design you took to roll your own?